# Sort Over Different Class Members

Tags: c++

I have a class that includes several members of type `double`.

Suppose I need to make a function that re-orders a vector of class objects based on the values of one of the members on the class. So:

```
class myClass{
    ...
    public:
       double x, y, z;
    ...
 }

void SpecialSort_x(std::vector<myClass>& vec) {
    // re-order stuff according to values of vec[i].x
    ...
}
```

But now, I want to be able to do the same re-ordering, but according to values of the other members of the class (`y` and `z` in the code above).

Instead of making two more functions that are identical to the first one, except with all references to `x` changed to `y` or `z`, I would like to make a single polymorphic function that can re-order the vector according to any of the members of `myClass`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a custom comparison function (object)?

Comment: Let's start by asking why you don't use `std::sort`.

Comment: Expanding on`dyp's comment, use `std::sort` with a lambda.

Comment: @Jon, @ Deduplicator, The re-ordering is not just a sorting. It requires more than a single comparison function (as far as I can tell). Also, I would like the function in the future to do more than just re-order. Perhaps return some values based on the values of the specific class member under consideration.

Comment: `std::sort` is the way to go, but to answer your stated question, you could make use of an argument of pointer-to-member type `double myClass::*`.

Comment: @DerrickTurk, I'm not familiar with how to use pointer-to-member types. Could you elaborate a bit on how I would be able to use them in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::sort`, combined with a lambda and a pointer to member thus:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class MyClass
{
public:
    double x, y, z;
};
typedef double MyClass::* Field;

void specialSort(std::vector<MyClass>& vec, Field field) 
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [field](const MyClass & a, const MyClass & b) -> bool
    {
        return a.*field < b.*field;
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClass> vec;
    Field member = &MyClass::x;
    specialSort(vec, member);

    return 0;
}
```

And you could also templatise the sort using:

```
template<class T>
void specialSort(std::vector<T>& vec, double T::* field)
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [field](const T& a, const T& b) -> bool
    {
        return a.*field < b.*field;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone suggesting alternate approaches given the problem description here.

However, if you ever really have the need to access a class member chosen at runtime, you can use a pointer-to-member type. There is usually a more elegant way to accomplish the effect you want, though.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct X {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
};

void operate_on_member(const X& x, double X::*pm)
{
    std::cout << x.*pm << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> xs {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    for (const auto& x : xs)
        operate_on_member(x, &X::a);
    for (const auto& x : xs)
        operate_on_member(x, &X::b);
    for (const auto& x : xs)
        operate_on_member(x, &X::c);
}
```